# как разделить столбец?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

есть поле с датами `"tr_day"` в след формате: `"0 10:23:26"`. нужно создать новое поле `"day"` вычленив из поля `"tr_day"` первый символ до пробела, например, `"0"`.
использую `str.split`:

```py
tr['tr_day1']=tr['tr_datetime'].str.split(' ',n=2,expand=True)
```

но выдается ошибка

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

что  я делаю не так?

Comment: Предлагаю привести [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

```
tr["tr_day1"] = tr["tr_datetime"].str.split().str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

Исходный фрейм

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   tr_datetime
0   0 10:23:26
1   1 11:11:11
2  20 20:20:20
```

Решение

```
df["tr_day1"] = df["tr_datetime"].str.extract(r"(\d+).*").astype("int16")
```

Результат:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   tr_datetime  tr_day1
0   0 10:23:26        0
1   1 11:11:11        1
2  20 20:20:20       20

In [15]: df.dtypes
Out[15]:
tr_datetime    object
tr_day1         int16
dtype: object
```